# can we show Account records on Contact?

Tags: salesforce

On Account object we have a related list called contact.If  we want to add contact we can use Contact related list. then contact related list will created. But on the contact i could n't find the Acccount name in Account related list on Contact. Both Accounts and contacts are m-m relationship

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit weird. And it's not really programming-related. If my answer doesn't help you - try asking again at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

The default setup in Salesforce is that Accounts and Contacts are in `1:n` relation. So you have related list of 0,1 or more Contacts under Account. But when you're on Contact there's only 1 Account to choose from. And it's the "Account Name" field, a lookup (foreign key), not a related list with exactly 1 item on it.

You're 1 click away from viewing the Account. If that's not enough, if you really want to display Account data on Contact - there are options such as formula fields or adding "record detail" component to the page and making it use Account Name instead of this Contact. You can see it on the right side in my screenshot:

[image]

When you make new Contact you can select existing Account or click "New" in the lookup and create one on the fly. But relation is still `1:n`, A contact will have 0 (*possible but an edge case and generally bad idea*) or 1 account.

Then there's a special table called [`AccountContactRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountcontactrelation.htm). It's used to model "*one guy working in multiple companies, for example being director in company XYZ small local branch and at the same time - head of accounting in company XYZ headquater*". If you want that, a real `m:n` relation - you might have to enable few things in Setup and configure your Salesforce like this training course: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/admin_intro_accounts_contacts/admin_intro_accounts_contacts_relationships

> But on the contact i could n't find the Acccount name in Account
>   related list

So... if you already have the "Contacts to Multiple Accounts" enabled and added to page layouts and stuff - then perhaps it's as simple as checking the Contact page layout and editing the related list to include Account Name. But I have a feeling you skipped few steps on the way.