# How do i add a related record to a lightning page layout

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to add a related record to a lightning page layout for BAN but don't have an update/new action to associate with it

My goal is  based on the BAN entered into the Case to  show the BAN page on the Case lightning page for a custom object

Carolyn

Comment: What is a BAN? Also, belongs to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what BAN is (some custom object specific only to your Salesforce org?) and how they're related to each other ;)

You have a lookup field on Case that points to BAN and you want to show more details than just the name/link? Check if what I did in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61280895/313628 is any help. You edit the Lightning Page, find "record detail" component, drop it somewhere, configure a bit, job done?